# How to listen for events without a websocket RPC?

Tags: events, ethers.js, websocket

Based on the docs of [ethersjs](https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/contract/contract/#Contract-on), I could use the `provider.on()` function to listen for events and perform some actions. However, would it still work if I don't have a websocket RPC URL?

If it still does work without a websocket RPC, how does it constantly listening for an event?

If it must have a websocket RPC to work, how else can I listen for an emitted event without using a websocket RPC in ethersjs?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do this without a websocket.
`provider.on()` is leveraging JavaScript event handlers, and has nothing to do with websockets. JS is an event-driven language.

Comment: Behind the scene, since without web sockets, does the library constantly polling for the event every second then? Otherwise, how does it know that a new event has occurred?

Comment: Behind the scenes, JS is an event-driven language. Read up on how the Event-Loop works for a deeper understanding. 
This is a good place to start
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop

Comment: To address your question about polling, it does *not* do any polling. It's an event-loop and a task queue. The events are processed from the task queue (which is a list of messages to be processed). You (the programmer) can add and remove events from the queue to be processed. Again, there is no polling.

Comment: I disagree with jstep's answer re: `provider.on` not using polling. The source code is peppered with polling code:
- https://github.com/ethers-io/ethers.js/blob/c80fcddf50a9023486e9f9acb1848aba4c19f7b6/packages/providers/src.ts/base-provider.ts#L977
- https://github.com/ethers-io/ethers.js/blob/c80fcddf50a9023486e9f9acb1848aba4c19f7b6/packages/providers/src.ts/base-provider.ts#L2102-L2124

Answer (score 1):

With provider.on() you can filter the events only but can not listen them in real-time. websocket connection is essential for subscribing to real-time event listening.
HTTP-based providers do not support this functionality.

Answer (score 0):

I actually does some polling behind scenes like @kyzooghost mentioned in the comments. The event-loop nature of JS doesn't have anything to do with the type of connection used to get events in realtime.